# Cannot restart Ubuntu

Tags: restart

I was doing the following things on Ubuntu 16.04 and all of sudden Ubuntu get stuck.

1. Delete boost library I installed in `/usr/lib` by using `rm libboost*`.
2. Using `cmake` to rebuild point cloud library and got some errors complaining about a line in cmakelist.txt.
3. Then I tried to open cmakelist.txt using editor but the editor cannot be opened. Then I decide to restart Ubuntu.

But it never shows the login screen. It keeps showing a black screen with one line saying `/dev/sda5: clean XXX/XXX files, XXX/XXX blocks`.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You didn't post enough output to get an understanding of what is happening.

Comment: I don't really know what your trying to say but let me guess and suggest. You have to drop down to `recovery mode`  and `mount` your file system in `rw` and undo or reverse whatever you installed with that lib. Please take some time to write down what you did before you begin don't be in a hurry. If all you did is in that `usr/lib` then it should be easy to fix!